# jQuery - timeout in for loop

Tags: jquery, loops, for-loop, timeout

I have written a bit of jQuery to loop through items in a array an display a random number and then move on to display another number. The problem is I want to put a delay inside the loop so that it shows the number for 2 seconds and then moves of to the next. so you see a random number it holds for 2 seconds and then moves on to the next. I have tried putting a timeout inside the loop but that didn't work. Any help would be amazing thanks.

```
function RandomNumberGenerator(){

    var myArray = new Array(99);

        for (var i=0; i< 99; i++) {
            myArray[i] = Math.floor(Math.random()*100)
            myArrayTwo[i] = Math.floor(Math.random()*100)
        }

        for (var i=0; i< 9; i++) {
            $('li.num').text(function(index) {

            // timeout needs to be here somewhere 

            return (myArray[i]);

            })
        }
});
}
```

Comment: why doesn't the timeout inside the loop work?

Comment: Try putting the timeout at the very end of the loop, instead of inside the function setting the text.

Comment: Where is `myArrayTwo` defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need to put the code that does the work (displays the random number and decides if it should continue) inside its own function. This function can also be a local variable inside `RandomNumberGenerator`:

```
    var displayNumber = function() {
        $('li.num').text(myArray[i++]);
        if (i < 100) {
            setTimeout(displayNumber, 2000);
        }
    };
```

The function above puts a number in `li.num`, increments `i`, and tells the browser to call the function again (using [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Window.setTimeout)) in two seconds -- but only if we have shown less than 100 numbers.

So when this function (`displayNumber`) is called for the first time, it displays one number and sets things up to call itself again after 2 seconds (to display another number, and so on). If it has displayed 100 numbers already it does not set the call up again, so at that point the repetition stops.

So you can now do:

```
    var myArray = new Array(99);
    for (var i=0; i< 99; i++) {
        myArray[i] = Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
    }

    var i = 0;
    var displayNumber = function() {
        $('#foo').text(myArray[i++]);
        if (i < 10) {
            setTimeout(displayNumber, 2000);
        }
    };

    displayNumber(); // to get the ball rolling
```

Answer (score 3):

note that this isn't the cleanest/better solution, but since nobody posted what you asked for, here's an implementation of the delay in your for loop :

```
var delay = 2000; //2 seconds
for (var i=0; i< 9; i++) {
    setTimeout(function(index){
       $('li.num').text(myArray[index]);
    },delay * i,i);
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't really want the timeout "in the loop", you want to update the number at the end of the timeout, then start *another* timeout that'll update the number, and repeat, until your end condition is met.

Answer (score 0):

Delaying the code in the function doesn't work. The browser won't show any updates as long as your code is running, so you have to exit out of the function before the change shows up.

So, you have to divide the work into pieces that you can call using `setTimeout` or `setInterval`.

Something like this:

```
function RandomNumberGenerator(){

  var myArray = new Array(99);

  for (var i = 0; i < 99; i++) {
    myArray[i] = Math.floor(Math.random()*100)
    myArrayTwo[i] = Math.floor(Math.random()*100)
  }

  var index = 0;
  var handle = window.setInterval(function() {
    $('li.num').text(myArray[index]);
    if (++index == 100) {
      window.clearInterval(handle);
    }
  }, 2000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the fairly concise type of construct I would use for this (using `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`).

```
var $li = $('li.num');  // Set a local variable for efficiency

var tloop = function(iter, num_of_iters, delay, $li){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $li.text(Math.floor(Math.random()*100)); 
        if (iter < (num_of_iters - 1))  tloop(iter+1, num_of_iters, delay, $li);
    }, delay);
};

tloop(0, 10, 2000, $li);  // Kick off the display
```