# Simon Game, Javascript settimeout and animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, settimeout

Can anybody help me to simulate animation of four div tags?
Simply for loop should wait until opacity of div tags change in 1 second.

```
function animateDiv(ar) { // ar contains div tag indexes. ex:[0,3,2,3,1,0,1,2,3]
    for (var i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
        var ind = "";

        if (ar[i] == 0) ind = ".red";
        else if (ar[i] == 1) ind = ".blue";
        else if (ar[i] == 2) ind = ".yellow";
        else if (ar[i] = 3) ind = ".green";
        var ok = false;
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(ind).css('opacity', 1);
            console.log("waiting " + " index: " + i);
            ok = true;
        }, 1000);

        if (ok == true) {
            $(ind).css('opacity', 0.7);
            console.log("Done!");
        }

    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/z8y2v5u1/

Comment: Mind giving a snippet/fiddle?

Comment: So the desired behaviour is that the first div gets more opaque for 1 second before going back to normal, then the next div gets more opaque for 1 second before going back to normal, and so forth, with the order of the divs specified in the array?

Comment: Something like [**this**](https://jsfiddle.net/gy5d0Lwy/)?

Comment: thank you Mohammad. Do you know other ways how to do it ?

Comment: See [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8080983/how-to-create-a-simple-settimeout-loop) or [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7457530/jquery-timeout-in-for-loop).

Comment: and how to change opacity back after 1 second?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gy5d0Lwy/1/

Answer (score 0):

A for loop can't wait for a timeout to finish, because the function you supply to `setTimeout()` is run asynchronously after the current function (and whatever called the current function) finishes. So the whole loop will run before the timeout happens.

You need to use a "pseudo-loop" that relies on `setTimeout()` to trigger the next iteration. Something like the following will work:

```js
function animateDivs(ar, cb) {
  var $divs = $(".red,.green,.blue,.yellow"),
    i = 0;

  (function next() {
    if (i === ar.length) {
      if (cb) cb();
    } else {
      var $div = $divs.eq(ar[i]).css('opacity', 1);
      setTimeout(function() {
        $div.css('opacity', 0.7);
        i++;
        next();
      }, 1000);
    }
  })();
}
animateDivs([0,3,2,3,1,0,1,2,3], function() { console.log("Finished")});
```

```css
div { width: 40px; height: 40px; display: inline-block; opacity: 0.7;}
.red { background-color: red;}
.green { background-color: green;}
.blue { background-color: blue;}
.yellow { background-color: yellow;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="red"></div><div class="green"></div>
<br/>
<div class="blue"></div><div class="yellow"></div>
```

The `next()` function changes the appropriate div to an opacity of 1, then uses `setTimeout()` to wait a second before changing the opacity back and then call `next()` again for the next index in the array.

I figured you might like some way to know when the animation had ended, so I've added a callback argument (`cb`) to `animateDivs()` that will be called after the whole array has been processed - in my example all it does is log something to the console, but you could use it to do something more interesting.